# SocketIO, can't send emit data from client

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm having the most odd problem trying to send data from a client browser to my node server using SocketIO. Sending from server to client works just fine, but the other way around I get an undefined error. Here's a quick bit of what it looks like, super simple.

**Node Server (app.js)**

```
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
  socket.on("pageReady", function(data) {
    console.log('pageReady called');
    console.log(data);
    return socket.emit('newline', '###SOCKET STARTED###');
  });
 socket.on("disconnect", function() {
    return console.log('disconnected');
  });
});
```

**Browser (client.js)**

```
var socket;

socket = io.connect("http://localhost:5678");

socket.on("newline", function(data) {
  return $('#socketData').append('<li>' + data + '</li>');
});

socket.emit("pageReady", "test");
```

Super simple, right? Nothing special. When I emit from server, works fine, however when the client calls "pageReady". node responds with this.

```
/Volumes/HOME/Users/user/git/sockettest/app.js:89
    console.log(data);
                ^
ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

Data should be returning "test", but isn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure that's the code?

Comment: in the code shown, there is no way that _data_ can be undefined anywhere it's used. it may===undefined, but the name _data_ will be known, and thus not a Ref error. since you're not doing anything with data, it should be fine even if undefined in value. there has to be something else not shown...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client should listen for the socket connection before attempting to emit to it:

```
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:5678");

socket.on("newline", function(data) {
  return $('#socketData').append('<li>' + data + '</li>');
});

socket.on("connect", function() {
  socket.emit("pageReady", "test");
});
```

Comment: @Victor Nope, it's not. Look more carefully at his last client line.